# Mysql Big table rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question.
I want to create a table that will grow really fast..
It's a notifications table. So every notifications for a user will be store in it.

So my question is should i use a BIGINT as primary key with auto increment?

Is that enough? Will i reach the max range of a bigint?

I also think to have a autoincrement field for each user..
so:
user | idnotification as autoincrement
userA|1
userA|2
userB|1
UserA|3
UserC|1
UserC|2

that sounds weird? no? is that the best way or only  PK with autoincrement is ok?

If i refer to facebook... do they use one id with autoincrement?

Thanks

Comment: bigint is a 64bit value. for ids, it should probably be unsigned, which means you've got 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 usable IDs available.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer!
i dont understand what you want to mean by :it should probably be unsigned

Comment: IDs are generally positive numbers, so there's no point in wasting half of  your ID field's range by allowing signed (e.g. negative) numbers. e.g. a signed 64bit number tops out at 9,223,372,036,854,775,808

Comment: ok.. i understand that ids are positive.. and i agree... but for my question,, you dont suggest me to use bigint autoincrement as id? What sould i use?

Comment: You can use as an ID, the bigint auto increment. You must think if this ID will be use as a FK in another table or multiple tables or just use it as a PK. If you use it for create PK use it, if don't, you must think if pass the ID through another tables as a FK have space problem in the future.

Comment: use whatever you want, but if you want auto_increment from mysql, it'll have to be a numeric field, and for the largest possible range of IDs, it'd have to be `bigint unsigned`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! i dont think i'll use it in another table. It will only as PK of this table!

Comment: Ok thanks Marc!!! seriously, i didnt know that we can put attribute on a field...i now see that i can chose : UNSIGNED, UNSIGNED_ZEROFILL..
Thanks for your hint..

Comment: So i have to chose UNSIGNED because an id is positive... right?